# Why are non-specific translation questions not allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are many reasons I ask this question, including translation is an important part of learning a non-mother tongue language, without a teacher, making this forum lose use to a lot of people.
People would get turned away by it's exclusivity. Edit: "This is not the case."

Another reason is english and spanish.stackexchange exist, defeating another purpose of this forum. Edit: "This is also not the case."

I trust that everyone here has good intentions and are not always looking for this kind of feedback.

Still I wonder why, why did someone make this decision (persist), why isn't there a tag for this and why isn't it called "misc-languages" then? Edit: "This isn't relevant anymore."

*I have to add that the motivation behind the question comes from a thread in the matter of interactive online translators.*

Comment: I was going to answer this question, too, since many people misunderstand Language Learning and MiscLanguagesThatDidNotFindItsOwnSiteYet. But I saw the language you chose to talk in comments with those who are trying to help... and I changed my mind. Before attacking users here, please consider reviewing the rules of this site. If you find it matching your views — okay, welcome to this place. Otherwise please consider finding a forum or a chat board where such behavior is tolerated.

Comment: Saying something is not the truth is not attacking, so I don't need to respond to this.
I expect better from a big forum like stack exchange, a place to help people.

Comment: "Saying something is not the truth is not attacking". Accusing someone of lying is an attack.

Comment: I didn't say you were lying, let stand intentional, I said the statement was a lie.

Comment: You literally said "That's a lie" in [your comment to my answer](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/why-are-non-specific-translation-questions-not-allowed?noredirect=1#comment1144_748). The word ["lie" always implies intention](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lie#Noun_2).

Comment: That link also shows examples of unintentionally lying, but if I (mis-)thought that saying it's a lie implied you were intentionally lying, I wouldn't have said it out of respect.

Comment: There is no such thing as unintentional lying. The word "lie" by definition implies intent.

Comment: Not according to the link you sent and to me before u told me; I'm saying. Lie as a verb u are 100% true, but as this, a noun, maybe not.

Comment: I do want to apologize anyways for that in this world it's a standard that half of people on tv scream, about politics for example, while neutral people get pushed away, making emotionless text for many easily sound angry like an attack. I can't make it better, but I have to come clean my messages easily fall under this easily miss-interpreted emotionless text.

Comment: What are non-specific translation questions?? I am a translator and have no idea what that means.

Comment: Questions about translating itself and not about a translation of some word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not everyone is familiar with this, but *language learning* is an academic sub-discipline of *applied linguistics* (hence the name).  There are some well-known researchers in these areas such as [Paul Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Nation) (noted for the ["four strands"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Nation#The_Four_Strands) approach to studying languages) and [Stephen Krashen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Krashen) (noted for the [input hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_hypothesis)).  These are the kinds of topics we're after here.

The reason translation questions (specific or not) are probably off-topic, is because the topic is generally not within the discipline of *language learning*.  (Similarly, math questions are off-topic at [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).)  However, translation-related questions which lean more towards language learning are probably okay, e.g., How can translation software be utilized to improve one's writing skills?

I haven't read your question, but judging from its title, it looks like you're after translation software recommendations.  I think asking for recommendations for translation software might be on topic at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) using the [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) tag.

Comment: Thank you, this is a way more descriptive response(in general) than I got there.
When asking it, I coincidentally immediately asked in a comment if it was the right place instead of software recs, u confirmed not. Now I learned how to interpret resource, contributing to this forum.

Comment: People are always asking about translations from and into all kinds of languages. Including you with Chinese. I feel that most of the questions like these are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The focus of this site is methods and hard-to-find resources for learning or teaching languages. The question [What is a good online translator with a wide variety of languages?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/5750/800) evidently does not fit that scope. Nothing in that (now deleted) question was about learning or teaching languages.

The claim that "translation is the core of learning a non-mother tongue language" is mistaken. Translation-based language teaching (see especially the [grammar–translation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar%E2%80%93translation_method)) was common a hundred years ago but is now considered completely outdated.

Comment: @KevinCrans "That's a lie". Please mind your language. You are not on a social network here.

Comment: @KevinCrans I live in Europe and have attended language courses in three different European countries. I have never been in a language class that relied on translation as a teaching method, except where the goal was to teach translation in itself. Learning word lists does not rely on translation tools, so I don't see how that argument is even relevant.

Comment: I had to provide my experience from (pre&) college to understand you.

Comment: I wouldn't dear to violate, not even on socials, I'm just making sure that if someone else would ask that question in their way, you'll treat them the same, else I feel violated.

Comment: My apologies, even though "resource" is still not clear to me, the other answer shows the right way to see the grey area. I delete the first comment and add it back on request.